# border-radius.htc not works

Tags: internet-explorer, css

I don't understand why border-radius.htc not working in IE. I downloaded it and put in same directory where my css file.

```
css/
 -- styles.css
 -- border-radius.htc
```

In styles.css:

```
...
.b_rounded {
    /* Для хороших браузеров */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px; /* KHTML */
    border-radius: 5px; /* CSS3 */
    /* Для плохих IE */
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* учим IE border-radius */
}
...
```

But in all versions of IE blocks with b_rounded class are not rounded. Why it is so?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the .htc file is in the same folder as your stylesheet. You may also need to add ".htc" to your server's [MIME types](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306231) to ensure it is served up properly.

You may also want to try [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/) instead.

Answer (score 2):

keep the .htc at at the top

```
...
.b_rounded {
/* Для плохих IE */
    behavior: url(border-radius.htc); /* учим IE border-radius */    
/* Для хороших браузеров */
    -moz-border-radius: 5px; /* Firefox */
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px; /* Safari, Chrome */
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px; /* KHTML */
    border-radius: 5px; /* CSS3 */

}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to this tutorial

http://dimox.net/cross-browser-border-radius-rounded-corners/

You need to use an `absolute path`

> And replace http://yoursite.com/ on your absolute path, where you have
>   placed the border-radius.htc file.

Answer (score 0):

use behavior: url("PIE.htc"), download it from http://css3pie.com/. Also you can use position
:relative and zoom:1 with it. It works exactly, i use it;)

Answer (score 0):

"border-radius.htc" doesnot works with external stylesheets. It only works with internal stylesheets or inline.